# How do I solve this error in clojure: java.lang.Exception: Too many arguments to def (NO_SOURCE_FILE:130)

Tags: java, clojure

I get

> java.lang.Exception: Too many arguments to def (NO_SOURCE_FILE:130)

when i test the map below. Please help me resolve the error.
Here is my code:

```
(def test_data
  "Create map test data for tbl_email "
   {:new-acc  1
    :email "test_get_account_3@mode-test.co"
    :token "pa55P0rt"
    :name "Mode Test"
    :idpass "0000"
    :msisdn 728547954})
```

Comment: I don't get any exception when I define this same map? How did u test? What did you do?

Comment: I am using emacs. So i use c-x c-e

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably using a clojure version less than 1.3. Versions prior to 1.3 do not support `def` with docstrings.

You should probably upgrade to clojure 1.5, or set the docstring in the metadata map of the var if you must use clojure 1.2 or earlier.

Comment: Thanx. Your response was helpfull